# Flutter check if app is running in iPad or iPhone

Tags: dart, flutter

I am using vibration in my app and since iPad doesn't support it, so I wanted to remove a button from my app which vibrates the device.

So, how can I get to know if my app is running in iPad or iPhone?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Use [device_info](https://github.com/flutter/plugins/tree/master/packages/device_info)

```
Future<bool> isIpad() async{
  DeviceInfoPlugin deviceInfo = DeviceInfoPlugin();
  IosDeviceInfo info = await deviceInfo.iosInfo;
  if (info.name.toLowerCase().contains("ipad")) {
    return true;
  }
  return false;
}
```

Comment: technically, this answer is wrong. The user can edit the name of the device and the `name` property.

Answer (score 16):

The usage of [device_info](https://github.com/flutter/plugins/tree/master/packages/device_info) is correct, but the `model` property should be used:

```
Future<bool> isIpad() async{
  DeviceInfoPlugin deviceInfo = DeviceInfoPlugin();
  IosDeviceInfo info = await deviceInfo.iosInfo;
  if (info.model.toLowerCase().contains("ipad")) {
    return true;
  }
  return false;
}
```

Answer (score 3):

Use [sizer](https://pub.dev/packages/sizer) and check if is a tablet or not with this control

```
SizerUtil.deviceType == DeviceScreenType.Tablet
```

Comment: This solution works well if you already use the sizer library (you can avoid bundling device_info_plus) or if you can't use async-await (usually when you are initializing). Just remember to use Platform.isIOS as a precondition.

Answer (score 3):

device_info does not exist, now use [device_info_plus](https://pub.dev/packages/device_info_plus):

```
Future<bool> isIpad() async{
  DeviceInfoPlugin deviceInfo = DeviceInfoPlugin();
  IosDeviceInfo info = await deviceInfo.iosInfo;
  if (info.model!=null && info.model!.toLowerCase().contains("ipad")) {
    return true;
  }
  return false;
}
```

Answer (score -2):

You can use the following code to check if the platform is IOS in your if condition:

```
Size size = WidgetsBinding.instance.window.physicalSize;
Platform.isIOS && size.width / size.height == 0.75;
```

Comment: [What Every Computer Scientist Should Know About Floating-Point Arithmetic](https://docs.oracle.com/cd/E19957-01/806-3568/ncg_goldberg.html)